# Can make a query without using $ this->query()?

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

I have more queries in mysql, but i not use the *$this->query()*, because I do not need to create arrays. in cakephp there any way? the function *this->query* force to go through the model.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [DboSource query method](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/dbo-source#method-DboSourcequery)